# Parsing int from a string after specific part in PHP

Tags: php, string, parsing, int

How do I parse an int, or ints, from a changing string every time a specific part occurs. For example:

```
$output = "jack john 123 jill £2310 peter paul 123 328190 john john peter 1 paul 049 peter paul 999";
```

I need to only the ints that are after "peter paul", which in this case are 123 and 999. Should work no matter how many times "peter paul" occurs. Parsing them to an array probably is the way to go?

Comment: a [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is the way to go

Comment: something like `(?<=peter paul )[\d]*` would be the regex

Comment: Better `(?<=peter paul\s+)[\d]+`

Comment: true. but would have to be `(?<=peter paul[\s+])[\d]+` (at least regex101.com gives error without the []). Or just no quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

For that you'd need a regular expression used by the php function [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). Specificly one with a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
<?php
// your input
$haystack = "jack john 123 jill £2310 peter paul 123 328190 john john peter 1 paul 049 peter paul 999";

// find the matches and write them into $matches
preg_match_all('/(?<=peter paul\s)[\d]+/', $haystack, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
// output
print_r($matches);
```

The regular expression `(?<=peter paul\s)[\d]+`*very simply* explained in normal language:

Find everything *after* (`?<=`) 'pater paul' followed by a whitespace (`\s`) that is a digit (`\d`) and occures from 1 to n times (`+`)

working snippet: https://3v4l.org/YsMuM

Comment: For some reason only seems to match the first one, according to regex101.com too.

Comment: it's the global flag `/g` at the end! We have to use preg_match_all. I've changed my answer.